# items overloading in list view while coming back to previous activity

Tags: android

I have a 2 activity's. Activity(1) contains list of items and I am going to call activity(2) with `onitemclick` on activity (1). So here problem is when I come back to activity(2) to activity(1), the items present in the activity(1) is getting added again(just double). How can I stop this? Can any one tell please. I'm a beginner to android. Your help should be appreciated.

Activity(1)

```
public class ClassesActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displayclass);
    Log.i("i'm in displayclass","activity");

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.classlistView1); 
    cv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.classlistView1);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(clicklistener); 
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    }

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list3);
    cv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
    try {
        Classes_list.main();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

public static class ItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long id) {

c3=Classes_list.c2[position];
Log.i("c3", c3.getName());
    Intent myIntent2 = new   
 Intent(view.getContext(),Methods_on_class_list_activity.class);
    view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent2);
}
```

---

this is my Methods_on_class_list_activity (2)

```
public class Methods_on_class_list_activity extends Activity {
private ListView listview, mv;
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static ArrayList<String> your_array_list9 = new ArrayList();
public ItemClickListener clicklistener = new ItemClickListener();
public static Method c5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.method_display);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fromclassto_methodlist);
    mv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fromclassto_methodlist);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(clicklistener);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {

    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list9);
    mv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
    try {
        Methods_List.methodexecution();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
}
public static class ItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long id) {
        c5=Parameter_List.metd[position];
        Log.i("c3", c5.getName());

    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(),Parameterlist_activity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent2);
}
```

Comment: Post code of main() method of Classes_list class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity Life Cycle call as follows
```

**Activity -1**

**Once Click the List item**

```
1)onPause()
5)onStopt()
```

**Activity-2**

```
2)OnCreate()
3)onStrat()
4)OnResume()
```

**While returning back to Activity-1**

```
1. onRestart()
2. onStart()
3. onResume()
```

So remove your code from `onStart()` which add items to `ListView`

Thats is why it adding twice.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: wr should i add the listView sir

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list9);
    mv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
    try {
        Methods_List.methodexecution();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



Put this code in onCreate of Activity(1).

Comment: @Chitrang sir  i added this code but when i run the activity app will going to die.